# How to get id of parent tables which haven't any foreign key with another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a structure of a table have many fields

| table_id | name_table | name_filed | PK | FK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | person | id | pk |  |
| 1 | person | name |  |  |
| 1 | person | age |  |  |
| 2 | dog | id | pk |  |
| 2 | dog | name |  |  |
| 2 | dog | owner |  | fk |
| 3 | phone | id | pk |  |
| 3 | phone | name |  |  |
| 3 | phone | owner |  | fk |

How to get id(s) of parent tables which haven't any foreign key with another table
in this case expected result is 1

I've tried

```
select distinct table_id from tables_structure where fk!=''
```

Also I've tried with group by

```
select table_id from tables_structure where fk!=''
group by table_id 
having fk!=''
```

Comment: Why do you need this "table"? All this information is available in the meta-data of your database. Ignoring that, your table does not have sufficient information for your goal. It is missing a critical piece of information about your foreign keys - and that is the table to which it is associated. Assume you had a table named "DogBreed" and that Dog had a FK to DogBreed. Given your table, how would you **know** that without assuming based on names?

Comment: It's probably a dynamic or runtime table, so not a real SQL table at all, but I'd like to here OP confirm that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that you are comparing to an *empty string*, generally we expect the empty value to be represented by a `null` value, so try comparing using `IS NULL`

```
select distinct table_id from tables_structure where fk IS NULL
```

But that isn't likely to help you here, your data represents an `UNPIVOT` structure, your second attempt would work if you used a `COUNT` in your `HAVING` clause, here we don't even have to compare nulls because `COUNT` will exclude nulls for us!

```
select table_id 
from tables_structure
group by table_id 
having COUNT(fk) = 0
```

---

If the values really are empty strings, and not nulls, then we can still use count with nulls by treating `''` as a null value using `NULLIF`:

```
select table_id 
from tables_structure
group by table_id 
having COUNT(NULLIF(fk,'')) = 0
```

We can't just filter by `fk <> ''` as that will modify the dataset and return ALL records.

You can use a `SUM` over a `CASE` statement that computes a `1` or `0` for each record, but now things are getting complicated:

```
select table_id 
from tables_structure
group by table_id 
having SUM(CASE fk WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE 1)) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting my question and aswering it!

Comment: No worries, I use a table structures like this for custom/dynamic tables and views that the end user can define so I recognised what you were doing.

Comment: For the NULL case, we can use: `HAVING MAX(fk) IS NULL`, which is similar to the use of COUNT(fk)   ... see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=433c785c00f08fdff9f9aaa86d853d0b

Comment: @JonArmstrong absolutely, I guess it comes down to personal opinion, I prefer to read `COUNT = 0`  because that is quite litterally what we are expecting, that there are no rows. I just find `MAX` misleading when I read the SQL back in my head. MAX works for empty strings too of course, not just null: `HAVING MAX(fk) = ''` or combine `NULLIF` into `HAVING MAX(NULLIF(fk,'')) IS NULL`. I expect the performance to be similar but suspect `COUNT()` is faster because there is no forced sorting or comparison with the previous _max_ value as it is computed.